# How to change the data type of a string into the same datatype of a contingent value?

Tags: python, string, pandas, type-conversion

I´m trying to implemen a filtering code:

For example:

```
import pandas as pd   
import operator              #this lets you do logical operations

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

Filter_column = input('> ')  # I will do a filter in this column
comparision = input('> ')    # Here goes the logical comparission (==, >, <, etc)
filter_value = input('> ')   # Here goes the value to do the filter 

if comparision == '=':       #Say comparision = '=' in this example

    filter_value.astype(type(df['Filter_column)].dropna()[0])) #!!!
    filter = operator.eq(df['Filter_column'],filter_value))
    dp = df[filter]
```

Then, dp is the filtered data set given the filter condition

In the line where I put the comment `#!!!` is the ideal method to convert the data type of the input string `filter_value`. Pandas can change the data type of the values of a column with `.astype()` method.
But that is not a valid method for a string. Is there a way to convert the data type of an input string to the same data type of an arbitrary given object?

Comment: What type do you want to turn it into?

Comment: I guess I got a solution to my problem: What I did was make `value_list = [filter_value]` then `Serie_value = pd.Series(value_list)` then `Value_convertion = Serie_value.astype(type(df[Filter_column].dropna()[0]))` then with the corresponding logical operation `filter = operator.eq(df[Filter_column], Value_convertion[0])` and finally apply the filter to the dataframe `filtered_data = df[filter]`. Presto!
This is a solution, If you have a more convinient one feel free to share it.